# Devolver Json del tipo "nombre_campo": valor con Java y Spring

Tags: java, json, hibernate

Estoy haciendo un API REST que consume datos de una BBDD mySQL y los devuelve en formato JSON.

Utilizo hibernate, por lo que tengo entidades de objetos "conectadas" con la base de datos **con sus respectivas notaciones** @Entity, Id etc y estas las devuelve perfectamente.

Pero aparte, tengo objetos que se forman a partir de consultas pero que no deseo almacenar en la base de datos, por lo que **no tienen notaciones** ni tabla en la base de datos.

¿Problema? Estos objetos son devueltos en JSON de la siguiente forma (Los que **no** tienen notaciones):

```
[
    [
        4,
        "media",
        "status",
        1497736800000,
        1503180000000
    ],
    [
        5,
        "alta",
        "status",
        1497736800000,
        1503180000000
    ]
]
```

Cuando los demás son devueltos así, en formato "clave" : valor:

```
[
    {
        "id_team": 1,
        "date": 1497887607000,
        "level": 0,
        "id_project": 1
    },
    {
        "id_team": 1,
        "date": 1497987784000,
        "level": 0,
        "id_project": 1
    },
]
```

El método que devuelve la forma "incorrecta" es este:

```
public List<TechnicalDependency> getUserTecDep(int id_project, int id_factory, int id_team, String id_user) 
{
    return (List<TechnicalDependency>)manager.createQuery("SELECT id_task, priority, status, init_date, duedate "
            + "FROM Task "
            + "WHERE assignee = '"+ id_user +"'").getResultList();

}
```

El método que devuelve valores en JSON como los deseo es este:

```
public List<Team_Level> getTeamLevels(int id_team, int id_project, String date1, String date2) 
{
    return (List<Team_Level>) manager.createQuery(
                "FROM Team_Level"
                + "WHERE date >= '"+date1+"' "
                + "AND date <= '"+date2+"' "
                + "AND id_team ='"+id_team+"' "
                + "AND id_project = "+ id_project).getResultList();
}
```

Los métodos son iguales, por lo que el error entiendo que está en la forma de mapear a JSON. El problema es que después no puedo (o no sé) mapearlo de nuevo a objeto si no tengo el clave-valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema no es que los objetos vengan o no vengan de la base de datos, el problema es que lo que recuperas de la base de datos no es lo que tú crees.

```
return (List<TechnicalDependency>)manager.createQuery("SELECT id_task, priority, status, init_date, duedate "
        + "FROM Task "
        + "WHERE assignee = '"+ id_user +"'").getResultList();
```

Esto te devuelve un `List<Object[]>`. El tipo devuelto por `createQuery` varía según la consulta, y el casting sólo comprueba que sea un `List`, sin importar la parametrización. La información de generics no está en la clase compilada así que no se puede hacer esa comprobación en tiempo de ejecución, esto se llama *type erasure*. Puedes ver más detalles en [esta respuesta mía en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717791/arraylistinteger-and-string-from-databean-type-mismatch-exception/28718004#28718004).

Así que cuando pasas a la librería JSON un `List<Object[]>`, en JSON queda como lista de listas.

Si lo que quieres es obtener un objeto a partir de cada fila de la consulta, la forma correcta es

```
return (List<TechnicalDependency>)manager.createQuery(
        "SELECT new TechnicalDependency(id_task, priority, status, init_date, duedate) "
        + "FROM Task "
        + "WHERE assignee = '"+ id_user +"'").getResultList();
```

Naturalmente, tu clase deberá tener el constructor adecuado.

En general, cada vez que hay problemas que mezclan varias capas (bases de datos, JSON, etc.), es buena idea probar de comprobar en los pasos intermedios que lo que tienes es realmente lo que esperas. Depurar un programa desde la capa web hasta la base de datos "todo junto" es muuuuy difícil.

Comment: Genial! No tenia ni idea de esto, soy novatísimo. He tenido que investigar un poco más acerca de lo que me has dicho porque inicialmente no funcionaba. Si alguien llega hasta aquí, que sepa que ademas hay que añadir por decirlo de alguna forma "la ruta completa" hasta la clase del objeto: "es.xxx.yyy.paquete.clase". Tras eso ha funcionado.

Muchísimas gracias, estaba muy atascado :)

Comment: Si la respuesta es correcta, deberías marcarla como tal. Mira [help] para ver como se hace.

Comment: Si, es que se envió sin querer el mensaje antes de terminar de escribirlo y estaba editando. Gracias de nuevo.